# Python - convert hex byte array to pure hex byte array

Tags: python

I am reading SML protocol based data from my power meter. From /dev/ttyUSB0 I receive the following data (excerpt):

```
b"\x1b\x1b\x1b\x1b\x01\x01\x01\x01v\x07\x00\x17\x06\xf7\x84\x08b\x00b\x00rc\x01\x01v\x01\x01\x07\x00\x17\x11\x9d\x81x\x0b\t\x01emh\x00\x00c_\xdd\x01\x01cl\x18\x00v\x07\x00\x17\x06\xf7\...
```

How can I convert this bytearray of hex values to a pure hex bytearray like `1b 1b 1b 1b`

Comment: It's not really clear what result you are after. `1b 1b 1b 1b` is not valid python. Can you show us in python what you are trying to convert this to?

Comment: This is a byte string, not a byte array. But even so, what do you mean by "pure hex byte array"? Do you want to output the data in a particular form? I think you need to learn about the difference between the data and its representation on the screen. If you are doing some calculations with this data, you should just use it directly. Don't worry so much about how it looks because this is perfectly acceptable binary data to use in python.

Comment: Just to emphasize: there is a distinction between the data and what python displays. Understanding that the output you see represents the data you want is the first step in continuing with your project.

Comment: It currently IS a pure hex byte array.  In fact, there's nothing called "pure hex byte".  Are you talking about displaying the data as hex bytes?  Or creating a simple hex byte string?   That's different.  One way: `print (" ".join(f"{x:02x}" for x in yourstring))`

Comment: Please ignore my overcomplicated comment, @ForceBru has the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really a "bytearray of hex values". It's just how Python *displays* this data to you. This bytearray (or maybe `bytes`) holds a sequence of integers - the actual bytes:

```
>>> list(b"\x1b\x1b\x1b\x1b\x01\x01\x01")
[27, 27, 27, 27, 1, 1, 1]
```

Individual elements are integers as well:

```
>>> b"\x1b\x1b\x1b\x1b\x01\x01\x01"[1]
27
```

If you want a *string* that contains hexadecimal numbers without `\x`, use the [`.hex` method](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex):

```
>>> b"\x1b\x1b\x1b\x1b\x01\x01\x01".hex()
'1b1b1b1b010101'
>>> b"\x1b\x1b\x1b\x1b\x01\x01\x01".hex(' ')
'1b 1b 1b 1b 01 01 01'
```